# Как прочитать Integer c помощью StringTokenizer?

Tags: java

Читаю информацию с текстового файла через String Tokenizer и вывожу на экран.

В методе processInputData нужно читать каждый токен в строке последовательно и запоминать его через set. У объекта currentStudent есть только один аргумент name типа string, остальные токены это числа homework.

Как прочитать integer токен c помощью метода set и класса String Tokenizer?

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test 
{
    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String fileData = "data.txt";
        FileReader readFile = null;
        try {
            readFile = new FileReader(fileData);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(readFile);
        String inputFile;
        
        try {
            inputFile = reader.readLine();
            
            while(inputFile !=null)
            {
                processInputData(inputFile);
                inputFile = reader.readLine();
            }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
        try {
            readFile.close();
            
        } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processInputData(String data) 
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ", ");
        String name = st.nextToken();
        Student currentStudent = new Student(name);
        currentStudent.setHomework1(cast(st.nextToken()));
        currentStudent.setHomework2(cast(st.nextToken()));
        currentStudent.setHomework3(cast(st.nextToken()));
        currentStudent.setHomework4(cast(st.nextToken()));
        currentStudent.setHomework5(cast(st.nextToken()));
        currentStudent.setHomework6(cast(st.nextToken()));
        System.out.println(currentStudent.toString());
    }

    private static int cast(String nextToken) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Информация в файле

```
Alice,44,79,85,72,77,57
Bob,79,94,70,71,71,51
```

Comment: А  ч то  говорят  "регулярные выражения"?  И почему бы сразу не читать весь файл в массив  строк?

Comment: Класс `StringTokenizer` являлся устаревшим ещё в [Java 7: _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), вместо него рекомендуется пользоваться `String::split` или регулярками.  Кроме того, для построчного чтения файлов следует пользоваться `try-with-resources`

Answer (score 1):

У вас не реализован метод `cast`, реализуйте его следующим образом:

```java
private static int cast(String nextToken) {
    return Integer.parseInt(nextToken);
}
```